# What is the best way to change the place of each box in Angular

Tags: angular

I have two boxes(Box 1- Box 2), want to change the place of each box after clicking on the button

[**each box is a component**]
[image]

After clicking

[image]

Comment: use grid design and change the classes for the rows.

Comment: I created a sample for you on stackblitz and updated my answer. check it out. hope can be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using css flex system

This solution doesn't require using ngFor. You can apply it to any static blocks in a container.

**html**

```
<div class="flex-column" [class.reversed]="reversed">
  <div class="box box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box box-2">Box 2</div>
</div>

<button (click)="reversed = !reversed">Change order</button>
```

**css**

```
.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.reversed {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

### Using Angular ngFor directive and reverse array in place

```
<div *ngFor="let box of boxes" class="box box-{{box}}">Box {{ box }}</div>

<button (click)="boxes.reverse()">Change order</button>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/ju4jlmrGpHK6zchVCtdN?open=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 3):

I created a sample for you here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qjwusr?file=src/app/app.component.css)
Use an array of the number of box e.g `let boxes = ["box1", "box2"]` and use `ngFor` for rendering the. after clicking on button use the `Array.reverse()` to change the place.
That's it!

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public boxes: string[] = ["Box1", "Box2"];

  toggle() {
    this.boxes.reverse();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="box-container" *ngFor="let box of boxes">{{box}}</div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="toggle()">Change order</button>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```css
.box-container {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  text-align: center;
}
```